# Video JS Fullscreen Doesn't work in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, fullscreen, video.js

Hardware: Dell Optiplex 760 (stock)
OS: Windows 7 Pro (Service Pack 1)
Browser: Safari 5.1.4

My Issue:
the fullscreen mode was unloading my video but not going to full screen and not loading the video back in when I click the fullscreen button.

```
Console Error Messages: 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.tech.ready(function(){
        this[method](arg);
})')
```

Comment: good you have a js error, but there is no js here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing the following change solved the error for me. I don't know whether this will work for everyone or not but it is working perfectly for my situation. I only need to support Safari.

File: video.js
Lines: 2706 and 2757 "// Check for browser element fullscreen support"
From:     if (requestFullScreen) {
To:       if (navigator.userAgent.match("Chrome") && requestFullScreen || requestFullScreen && this.tech.supportsFullScreen()) {

Without the Chrome check this thing fullscreen won't work in chrome.

And you have to make the change to both lines mentioned above. If you don't add it to the cancel function then you won't be able to cancel.

Comment: I also added the following to changes to line 753 so that the control bar only fades out when in full screen

    player.addEvent("play", this.proxy(function(){
  this.fadeIn();
  this.player.addEvent("mouseover", function(){
   if( document.body.classList.contains( 'vjs-full-window' ) ) {
    myPlayer.controlBar.fadeIn()
    console.log("moused over");
   }
  });
  this.player.addEvent("mouseout", function(){
   if( document.body.classList.contains( 'vjs-full-window' ) ) {
    myPlayer.controlBar.fadeOut()
    console.log("moused out");
   }
  });
    }));